Is there a induction proof that $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(b, a \bmod{b})$?
I know how to prove the equation $$\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(b, a \bmod{b}).$$  But I don't use induction.  I don't find it natural to use induction in this case because I usually think of induction when a proposition $P(i)$ is connected to $P(i + 1)$, that is, when I think it is connected.  The gcd-equation, though, goes from the pair $(a, b)$ to the pair $(b, a \bmod{b})$, so the natural numbers involved in the problem are not obviously connected in a $(n + 1)$-manner.  Despite the equation above allowing a recursive algorithmic definition of the GCD:
def gcd(a, b):
  if b == 0:
    return a
  return gcd(b, remainder(a, b))

that doesn't really provide a proof by induction---or does it?  The inductive-step is computed without combining the steps in any way, so that does not suggest to me a proof by induction.  But I will change my mind when I look at the extended GCD because the steps really are combined:
def egcd(a, b):
  if divides(b, a):
    return b, 0, 1
  q, r = divmod(a, b)
  m, x, y = egcd(b, remainder(a, b))
  return m, y, x - q*y

But I myself still cannot figure out a proof by induction of the GCD.  Although the connection between the coefficients x, y (of the GCD linear equation) are clear from the pseudocode, the relation $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(b, a \bmod{b})$ is still not easy to capture by induction.
So I'm wondering whether experienced people would easily find a proof by induction and whether we could expect a proof by induction in this case despite it being nontrivial.

You can prove the equation by induction on a, using the fact that gcd(a,b)=gcd(a-b, b) as an induction step (assuming a>=b), so the inductive assumption here gives you (since a-b < a) that gcd(a-b, b) = gcd(b, (a-b) mod b), where (a-b) mod b=a mod b.

Why do you care whether your proof is by induction?

Induction and recursion are pretty much the same things.

Thank you for the directions, @MarcinWrochna.  Tomek, I'm interested in understanding induction.  Thanks, freakish.

I'm going to prove for all $a \in \mathbb{N}, b \in \mathbb{N} \setminus\{0\}$. It can be easily extended to $a \in \mathbb{Z}, b \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus\{0\}$
Let $r = a \mod b$, then $a = kb + r$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}$. $(a_k)$ be the corresponding sequence. We're going to prove that for each $b,r$, the equation is true for all $k$, therefore it's true for all $a,b$.

Step 1: the formula is true for $k = 0$. This is obvious since $a_0 = r$.
Step 2: if the formula is true for $k = n$, then it's true for $k = n+1$. We have:
$$a_{n+1} = a_n +b$$
Thus $\mathrm{GCD}(a_n,b) \mid a_{n+1}$. Similarly, $\mathrm{GCD}(a_{n+1},b) \mid a_{n}$. Consequently,  $\mathrm{GCD}(a_n,b)$ is a common divisor of $a_{n+1}$ and $b$, and vice versa, therefore (*):
$$\mathrm{GCD}(a_n,b)\leq \mathrm{GCD}(a_{n+1},b)$$
$$\mathrm{GCD}(a_{n+1},b)\leq \mathrm{GCD}(a_n,b)$$
Obviously, $\mathrm{GCD}(a_{n+1},b) = \mathrm{GCD}(a_n,b)\Rightarrow \mathrm{GCD}(a_{n+1},b) = \mathrm{GCD}(b,r)$
Step 3: Conclusion: $\mathrm{GCD}(a_{k},b) = \mathrm{GCD}(b,r)$ for all $k$.

Equivalently, $\mathrm{GCD}(a,b) = \mathrm{GCD}(b,a \mod b)$ for all $a \in \mathbb{N}, b \in \mathbb{N} \setminus\{0\}$ $\Box$
(*): this is basically proving $\mathrm{GCD}(a+b,b) = \mathrm{GCD}(a,b)$ so skip if you know already

Thank you very much for the lecture!
